# NumPy casts lower precision to higher precision in floating point arithmetic

Tags: python, numpy, precision

This is no doubt the case in other (and maybe all) languages, but I've only testing in Python. My question is this:
When doing arithmetic on two values with different precision, why does NumPy return the result in the dtype of the value with highest precision?

For example

```
import numpy as np

single = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], np.float32)  
double = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], np.float64)

diff = single-double

print "single data type -", single.dtype  
print "double data type -", double.dtype  
print "diff data type -", diff.dtype
```

yields:

> single data type - float32
>   double data type - float64
>   diff data type - float64

As I understand floating point precision, the extra second half of the representation of `diff` is not accurate. In that case, whats the reason for casting the result to the highest precision rather than the lowest precision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is a principle in numerical computation called catastrophic cancellation.

Consider the slightly, lesser example between two floating point numbers.
3.0000900 - 3.000, if it were cast down to 4 decimal places, or in your case cast down to 4 bytes, our resulting value is 0. However those values are not actually the same! The phenomenon that I just demonstrated above is called catastrophic cancellation. We are essentially losing information as a result of truncating or even rounding for that matter.

To avoid this, the resultant of these operations are always type cast to the more precise type, since the information lost is minimal.

Answer (score 4):

That's called type coercion and at least in NumPy it will always coerce to the type with higher precision because that way you don't lose precision accidentally and you don't get overflows.

For example (regarding "overflow") with coercion to `float64` it (sort-of) works:

```
>>> np.float64(1e40) - np.float32(1)
1e40
```

But if it would coerce to `float32` you would get:

```
>>> np.float64(1e40).astype(np.float32) - np.float32(1)
inf
```

That's because the biggest `float32` is `3.4028235e+38`.

```
>>> np.finfo(np.float32)
finfo(resolution=1e-06, min=-3.4028235e+38, max=3.4028235e+38, dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is mostly from [mathematics and the types of numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_types_of_numbers).

The types of types64 contains the ensemble of types32 in the same way the types of real numbers (floats) include the types of integer numbers.

Whenever you perform calculations, you can guarantee to deliver a satisfying result if you map your results set inside a larger data container (integer type 64 instead of 32), but you cannot guarantee that you will not truncate the results if mapping a set of values within potentially shorter containers, which means producing invalid results.

This has always been this way with float and int too. In most languages, multiplying a float with an int results in a float, because a float (real number) can mathematically contain an int, while the opposite is not true (the integer type does not contain the real numbers).